# Validity of Volga-Dnepr An-124 Grounding in US

Tags: faa-regulations, airworthiness

Around June 10th, a Ukranian court [issued an order](https://www.ch-aviation.com/portal/news/78883-ukrainian-court-orders-seizure-of-5-volga-dnepr-an-124s) grounding 5 of Volga-Dnepr's An-124 cargo planes, citing maintenance checks conducted without OEM (i.e., Antonov) authorization. According to FlightAware, one of those planes (tail no. RA-82078) has been sitting on the ramp at Huntsville International since June 26th, after landing in the U.S. for the first time since the court issued the grounding order. Has the FAA grounded that plane in response to the Ukranian court order, or are Volga-Dnepr leaving it there for other reasons? It's definitely not a grounding of all An-124s, since Antonov Airlines continues to operate An-124s in the U.S.

Comment: as you say, the grounding only involves 5 aircraft of one specific operator, so of course other operators aren't involved. As to why that one's sitting there, you'd have to ask the operator, or file a FOIA request with the FAA.

Comment: Regardless of what the FAA does, Volga-Dnepr would be in breach of the court order if it flew the plane anywhere in the world, and therefore subject to legal sanctions.

Comment: @David Richerby, Volga-Depnr's public position is (or at least was a few weeks ago) that the order has no validity outside the Ukraine and intend to continue operations regardless.

Answer (score 2):

It only makes sense USA enforces the action of Ukraine, if it wishes Ukraine does the same in the future (as noted by @JuanJimenez). Luckily, those countries (states) already agreed to the following terms as part of joining ICAO:

> 4.2.1 State [Country] of Design
>
> 4.2.1.1 The State of Design of an aircraft **shall:**
>
> a) transmit to every Contracting State which has in accordance with 4.2.3 a) advised the State of Design that it has entered the aircraft on its register, and to any other Contracting State upon request, any generally applicable information which it has found necessary for the continuing airworthiness of the aircraft, including its engines and propellers when applicable, and for the safe operation of the aircraft, (hereinafter called mandatory continuing airworthiness information) and notification of the suspension or revocation of a Type Certificate;
>
> *Note 1.— The term "mandatory continuing airworthiness information" is intended to include mandatory requirements for modification, replacement of parts or inspection of aircraft and amendment of operating limitations and procedures. Among such information is that issued by Contracting States in the form of airworthiness directives.*
>
> *Note 2.— The Continuing Airworthiness of Aircraft in Service (Cir 95) provides the necessary information to assist Contracting States in establishing contact with competent authorities of other Contracting States for the purpose of maintaining continuing airworthiness of aircraft in service.*

(Source: Annex 8 to the Chicago Convention; bold emphasis mine.)

That's the legalese for when a country that has designed a plane, finds an issue (e.g., the alleged unauthorized maintenance making those affected not airworthy), **shall** notify the other contracting states (other ICAO member states).

If any state wishes to ignore that it has been notified that certain planes are not airworthy, will surely have consequences, but this is a better fit for Law.SE.

Comment: Except this was not a Ukranian aviation authorities action, it was a court action. A judge cannot declare an aircraft unairworthy.

Comment: @JuanJimenez: It says the **State** of Design (not the National Aviation Authority). It's also why I said USA not FAA. USA is the party to ICAO (not FAA; technically speaking), likewise for Ukraine. Regardless how they internally reach their decisions, e.g., a court launching an investigation into the airworthiness, will depend on each country's legal framework. The end result is Ukraine communicating to USA that those planes are not airworthy.

Comment: This isn't an airworthiness issue, it's a political issue morphed into a civil court issue. "The airline and the manufacturer have been deadlocked since 2014 after the Crimean Crisis and the ensuing civil war in the Donbass with pro-Russian separatists, led to the severing of all relations between Russia and Ukraine." Russia is trying for political reasons to force anyone operating the aircraft to have to go there for the heavy checks and airworthiness extensions.

Comment: @ymb1 the aircraft are grounded, not declared to not be airworthy. 2 different things. Aircraft can for example be grounded to prevent them from escaping debt collection, or if considered contaminated and requiring cleaning.

Comment: @jwenting: I'm going by what was reported in OP's link: *"[V]iolation of the provisions of the ICAO Convention on International Civil Aviation and **Airworthiness** Guidelines"*